# Problems in reading images in Open CV 2.4.7

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I recently started to work with OpenCV in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. I wrote a simple code to open an image located on the project folder and I'm getting an error. This is the debug output:

'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenCV_Test\Debug\OpenCV_Test.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv247\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_core247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv247\build\x86\vc10\bin\opencv_highgui247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9200.16658_none_bf1359a245f1cd12\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCV_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x757E4B32 in OpenCV_Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00E5FA28.

Unhandled exception at 0x757E4B32 in OpenCV_Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00E5FA28.

First-chance exception at 0x757E4B32 in OpenCV_Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00E5EB10.

Unhandled exception at 0x757E4B32 in OpenCV_Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00E5EB10.

First-chance exception at 0x0F202BD6 (opencv_highgui247d.dll) in OpenCV_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018.

Unhandled exception at 0x0F202BD6 (opencv_highgui247d.dll) in OpenCV_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018.

First-chance exception at 0x0F202BD6 (opencv_highgui247d.dll) in OpenCV_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018.

Unhandled exception at 0x0F202BD6 (opencv_highgui247d.dll) in OpenCV_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018.

Can anybody help me with that? Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("img.jpeg");
    namedWindow("Image Sample");
    imshow("Image Sample", image);
    waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that error message is not very helpful. Is that really all you got? Can you use a debug build of OpenCV? Are you compiling with debug symbols?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you try using VS 2012 or 2010..? There have been some changes in VS 2013 and OpenCV hasn't adapted yet.

Comment: I actually tried the same code on Visual Studio 2010 and got the same message

Comment: Make sure that the OpenCV library was built with the same version of compiler and libraries as your application. If they are not built with the same version the layout of objects may be different and cause problems just like this.

Comment: I already checked it, but unfortunately it is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Even though lots of things *could* be the problem, the most likely issue is that the image could not be found.

You can make sure by giving the complete path to `img.jpeg` instead of the relative path you have now.

Comment: I tried do do it, but nothing changed